# How can I set values for native Mailchimp's merge tags in Mandrill?

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I exported a Mailchimp's template to Mandrill.
template has a native Mailchimp merge var like this:

```
 *|LIST:COMPANY|*
```

I want to set a value manually to this merge var using the official Mandrill API PHP wrapper. using function sendTemplate(....)
I tried:

```
'global_merge_vars' => array(array(
  'name' => 'LIST:COMPANY',
  'content' => 'my company name'
))
```

or

```
'X-MC-MergeVars' => array('{"LIST:COMPANY":"my company name"}')
```

or in the second parameter of sendTemplate() function:

```
array(array(
  'name' => 'LIST:COMPANY',
  'content' => 'my company name'
))
```

but none of them works. there is a way to do this?
regards

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the colon in the merge tag from MailChimp [isn't supported in Mandrill](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-). I was able to get this to work by removing the colon and replacing it with a supported character like an underscore, i.e. `LIST_COMPANY`.